# How find and install old firefox version

Tags: software-installation, firefox, downgrade

I have already installed firefox 52.0.1 (64), trying to install *50.1.0 (64)*

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=50.1.0
```

answer

```
E: «firefox» version «50.1.0» is not found.
```

---

More information:

```
$ apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
Version: 52.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Version: 52.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Version: 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: @muru It would be good for me, but I have not found correspond *deb* packages. I've found [tar.bz2](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.1.0/firefox-50.1.0.linux-x86_64.sdk.tar.bz2) and I can't install one on my Ubuntu...

Comment: I replaced the version in the commands in the linked post, and `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/firefox-mozilla-build_52.0.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` downloads a ~60M deb file for me.

Comment: I think it should be good for me - thanks a lot